# Is there a non-solvable amenable torsion-free countable ICC group?

Tags: group-theory

*Question*: Is there a non-[solvable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group) [amenable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group) [torsion-free](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Torsion-free_group) [countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) [ICC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_conjugacy_class_property) group?
If so, is there a classification program of such groups?

*Remark:* In the torsion case, there is the [finitary symmetric group $S_{\infty}$](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Finitary_symmetric_group) . A comment of @studiosus in a deleted question, indicates the [Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(1,2)$](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Baumslag-Solitar_group:BS(1,2)), in the solvable case.

Comment: Do you know any nonsolvable amenable torsion free groups?

Comment: Related: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.7605.pdf

Comment: I don't know, perhaps this paper contains examples.

Comment: I think so too: I think you should take your time reading it.

Comment: It is finitely generated and solvable.

Comment: @studiosus: do you have a reference for $\mathbb{Z} ≀ \mathbb{Z}$ (presentation and solvability)?